# QSerialPort::SerialPortError(PermissionError)

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to open the connection for reading and writing (I am working on Windows) but the program says that I have no permission and I don´t know how to open it.

Here I post which part of code give me the error

```
if (!serial.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) { 

    qDebug("SERIAL PORT - NOT OPENED") ;
    qDebug()<<"error code = "<<serial.error();

    processError(tr("No puedo abrir el puerto %1, error code %2")
                 .arg(serial.portName()).arg(serial.error()));
    return;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running it as an administrator?

Comment: Your code requires elevation rights if you have no permission for that operation. Try elevating your code by impersonation of a user with higher elevated privileges or elevate your program by running as user with just the right privileges or administrator.

Comment: I tried running as an administrator and it doesn´t work, and I don´t know how to elevate my program by running as user with just the right privileges or administrator

Comment: If you've tried it as admin I suspect it's what you are trying to open. Try posting the code that shows us that as well.